# Maping an object full of html elements in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm struggling to map my object which contain some HTML elements, I just want all my li elements in my ul.

I've been trying several mapping usages, but I couldn't make it works.

```
test(){ 

    var l;
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.props.paginationData.totalPage; i++){
        if (i == parseInt(this.props.paginationData.currentPage)){
            l += <li className="page-item active"><a className="page-link" href="#">{this.props.paginationData.currentPage}</a></li>
        }
        else{
            l += <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" onClick={()=>this.props.search(this.props.sortData.orderby, this.props.sortData.sens, this.props.searchTerm, i)} >Précedent</a></li>
        }
    }
    return l

}
render(){



    if (this.props.paginationData.totalPage <= 5){
        return(


            <div className="container">     
                <ul className="pagination"> 
                    {this.test().map(obj => {obj.l} )}
                 </ul>
            </div>  
        )}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `test()` isn't returning an array but a string, so there's nothing to map. `var l = [];` then use `l.push(<li ...></li>)` then use `{ this.test() }`

Comment: The main problem is that you cannot compose HTML by adding together JSX elements. In React, `<p>Hello</p> + <p>World</p>` ends up as `[object Object][object Object]` because the `+` causes the Objects to turn into strings. Instead you need to put the in an array. Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/0pj9v5x0n

Answer (score 0):

I took time to indent your code and fixes some mistake you made such as :

```
  {this.test().map(val => {
    val; // map already return the value inside the object you don't need to do val.l
  })}

  let l = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.props.paginationData.totalPage; i++) {
  // using scoping declaration variable to avoid scope trouble
```

Also your l is a string, it should be an array if you want to iterate it.
 Could also doing it by simply rendering your string with `{ this.test() }` int your jsx, the example below is with the use of an array

```
test() {
  let l = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.props.paginationData.totalPage; i++) {
    if (i == parseInt(this.props.paginationData.currentPage)) {
      l.push(
        <li className="page-item active">
          <a className="page-link" href="#">
            {this.props.paginationData.currentPage}
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    } else {
      l.push(
        <li className="page-item">
          <a
            className="page-link"
            onClick={() =>
              this.props.search(
                this.props.sortData.orderby,
                this.props.sortData.sens,
                this.props.searchTerm,
                i
              )
            }>
            Précedent
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    }
  }
  return l;
}
render() {
  if (this.props.paginationData.totalPage <= 5) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul className="pagination">
          {this.test().map(val => {
            val;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify a bit what you did there. What about this solution:

```
render() {
    let paginationButtons = [];
    this.props.paginationData.forEach((button, index) => {
        if (index !== this.props.paginationData.currentPage) {
            paginationButtons.push(<li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" onClick={()=>this.props.search(this.props.sortData.orderby, this.props.sortData.sens, this.props.searchTerm, i)} >Précedent</a></li>);
        }
        else {
            paginationButtons.push(<li className="page-item active"><a className="page-link" href="#">{index}</a></li>);
        }
    })
    return (
        <div className="container">     
            <ul className="pagination"> 
                {paginationButtons}
             </ul>
            }
        </div>  
    )
}
```

You can of course migrate the part before the `return` to a separate function like `test()` and use it in the render simply like `{this.test()}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
_getPaginationButtons = (paginationData)=>{
return paginationData.map((res,key)=>{
    if (key !== this.props.paginationData.currentPage) {
      return (<li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" onClick={()=>this.props.search(this.props.sortData.orderby, this.props.sortData.sens, this.props.searchTerm, i)} >Précedent</a></li>))
     }

   else {
    return (<li className="page-item active"><a className="page-link" href="#">{index}</a></li>)
    })
    }


    render() {
    const {paginationData} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="container">     
                <ul className="pagination"> 
                    {this._getPaginationButtons(paginationData)}
                 </ul>
                }
            </div>  
        )
    }
```

I don't know what is your if statement logic but it should work